# Reporting Services C# Collapsible Detail Subreport in Row Passing Parameters

Tags: c#, web-applications, reportingservices-2005

I have a report that within its grid needs to show details for each row.
Below the data row of the main report I have a subreport that lists some detail for the row.
It is hidden or show by clicking a field / text box in the 'parent row'.

I need to use a field value from the parent data to populate each detail row.
So far I have not been able to pass this value, and I am receiving this error message:

Data retrieval failed for the subreport, 'SiteProfileRate', located at:

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate the help.

Thanks for any and all help and assistance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I pieced it together...
For those interested, this is what worked for me...

```
    this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(SubreportProcessingEvent);

    void SubreportProcessingEvent(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        ds = getSubReportData(e.Parameters[0].Values[0]);
        ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("SqlDataSourceProg", ds.Tables["SiteProfileSvcRate"]);

        rds.Name = "SiteProfileSvcRate";

        e.DataSources.Add(rds);
    }

    private DataSet getSubReportData(string strSvcId)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlParameter[] sParam = new SqlParameter[1];

        sParam[0] = new SqlParameter("svcid", strSvcId);
        ds = dac.GetDataSet("xwiWR_SP_SiteProfile_SvcRate_Current", sParam, "SiteProfileSvcRate");

        return ds;
    }
```